# object reference not set to an instance of an object : source

Tags: c#, exception

I have an object named "groupRead" which is null so that's why it's throwing an exception of "object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I'm trying to access this object property.

[image]

In exception catch, I'm capturing this exception's stacktrace, exception message, and the method name where it generating this exception. But I want to capture the name of the last source name which in this case it is the object "groupRead" as in the above image.

So, what is the property of the exception which is displaying this message "groupRead was null" as displayed in the Exception window, It would be good and will be more accurate to find the bug's exact source.

Current catch block:
[image]

Comment: Please post actual code, instead of screenshot. It will be easier for people to help you.

Comment: The runtime will do a null check before calling its method, so if the object is null, you won't get the name of the property/method.

Comment: @aca I wanted to show the exception window (second line: groupRead was null) that's why I added a screenshot instead of code, although it was a general question that doesn't even need code to explain, thanks I will add code as well for next time.

Comment: @shingo thanks brother, but still is there any feature or any other third-party resource available to get the object name at runtime exception catch so that I can capture it as in the attached screenshot (Exception window, second line: groupRead was null).